# `numpy.corrcoef` returns array having unexpected shape

Tags: python, numpy, pearson-correlation

I'm doing the following:

```
from numpy import corrcoef
R= corrcoef(X, X, rowvar=False)
```

where `X` has shape (M, N).  (There are `M` observations, each consisting of a length-N vector).  I expected to get an array having shape (N, N), but instead I got an array having shape (2*N, 2*N).  Any explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Please give a runnable example that illustrates the issue

Comment: `R= corrcoef(X, X)`

Answer (score 0):

Each NxN quadrant is a Covariance matrix.

```
a3 = corrcoeff(a1,a2,rowvar = False)
```

a1 and a2 are obviously same size.

1. top left quadrant is variation of each variable of a1 with respect to a1
2. top right quadrant is variation of a1 with respect to a2
3. bottom left is variation of a2 with respect to a1
4. bottom right is variation of a2 with respect to a2

If a1 and a2 are same, you'll find diagonals of each quadrant are one's.

If you just want to see the how each variable varies:

```
a3 = numpy.cov(a1,a1,rowvar=False)[:N,:N]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, for some reason `np.cov` and `np.corrcoef` both concatenate the inputs and then *always* do an auto-covariance of the concatenated array.  Luckily, you can just not give a second array and you'll get the auto-covariance of the first parameter (since by deafault [`y = None`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html).)

```
R = corrcoef(X, rowvar = False)
```

If you weren't doing autocovariance, your best bet would be either to use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) with `metric = 'correlation'` or just do the calculation out longhand:

```
X_ = X - X.mean(-1)
Y_ = Y - Y.mean(-1)
X_var = np.einsum('ij, ij -> j', X_, X_)
Y_var = np.einsum('ij, ij -> j', Y_, Y_)
R = (X_.T @ Y_) / (X_var[:, None] * Y_var)
```